# Python: Importing from a sub-directory (reference within the subfolder)

Tags: python, import, module, package, subdirectory

I have a file

```
`XYZ\Application.py`
```

And a package including multiple Python files, e.g.

```
XYZ\Python\UserInterface.py
```

Inside of the **Application.py** I am just using the **UserInterface** so I import it with

```
 from Python.UserInterface import UserInterface
```

(the Python folder contains a `__init__.py` (if that's even important)). But the UserInterface again uses many different files/modules which are stored in the same directory and imported by the UserInterace. But if I just say `from Reader import Reader` I get this `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Reader'` error. Do I really need to reference every import inside the package with `Python.whatever`?

Comment: Reader module exists in Python directory??

Comment: Yes, exactly, the Reader is inside the same directory as the UserInterface which is the "Python" directory.

Comment: `from Reader import Reader` line written in Userinterface.py or Application.py

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
from .Reader import Reader
```

or

```
from Python.Reader import Reader
```

in `UserInterface.py`

Comment: My acutal code is just `from Reader import Reader` but does not work. The second version of you seems to work but well I would need to change like 100 imports in all my files then...